# Why are the created modules not found when I run colab?

Tags: computer-vision, google-colaboratory

I am using colab for a computer vision project, although I use the sys or os modules to configure the path of the modules, it does not find them. The image also shows that I imported the module which is executed normally, I don't know what happens to colab, before if it was executed normally.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dUoL9.png)